# Yakuake skin removes settings menu

Tags: themes, settings, yakuake

I recently installed yakuake, and tried different themes/skins (whatever the correct denomination).

I choose one, but failed to notice that it removed the "button" to access the menu, so I can no longer access the settings and change anything, which is annoying.

I've tried purging yakuake then installing again, but no luck, the skin/theme is still there.

Using KDE 4.13.3

There may be a simple solution, and I'll feel like a fool when someone points it out, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find where the skin/themes are stored, and delete the skin/theme. This should work, as it will no longer have the files to load the skin.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much. I knew I would be embarassed by the simplicity of the solution. My skins were under /home/[username]/.kde/share/apps/yakuake/

Answer (score 13):

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
Opens configure yakuake

Answer (score 3):

You can manually edit the yakuake configuration file - open `~/.kde/share/config/yakuakerc` and look for the `[Appearance]` section and just comment out the `Skin` option by adding a `#` character at the front of the line.

Then kill yakuake by running `killall yakuake` and when you start it again it should revert to the default theme.

I personally like the "Breeze Minimal" theme which doesn't have a settings button, so I use this trick to get to the settings dialog when I need to, and then set it back to the minimal theme.

If you just want to edit the global keyboard shortcut for Yakuake, though, then you can just use the standard KDE global shortcuts configuration panel - you don't need the Yakuake settings dialog for that.

Comment: `vim ~/.config/yakuakerc` currently on KDE

Comment: Correct - as of Plasma 5, KDE applications have moved to use the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (which is most often `~/.config`) as the base directory for configuration files, instead of `~/.kde/share/config`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> is the key combination you're looking for (that's "control" plus "shift" plus the "comma" key).

It brings up the master configuration page in case an installed theme from an oblivious theme builder breaks your menu items.

I'm posting this for future users of Yakuake: an incredible pull-down terminal!

Comment: So, I have been told that reviving a thread that died 5 months ago is not actually considered bumping a zombie thread on StackExchange, and my comment was edited. Hm. Thank you, Zanna?